# Iphone/ipad architecture suggestions for game look-and-feel app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

All you ios architects out there, please help me choose architecture/technology for the following iphone/ipad app.

The app itself is a financial app, but we want more of a game look-and-feel of the app, so we probably don't want to use the builtin looks of the cocoa widgets. The elements on the screen will probably be some kind of blob-shaped images.

The app will essentially have five "blob"-shaped areas, spread out evenly across the screen. One of the blobs will be centered and larger than the other ones. Within each blob there will be clickable areas which will pop up "details" and menu-action blobs. These blobs are also graphics objects and must not take over the whole screen. The blobs should animate nicely when popping up. The graphics elements will have a couple of lines of text, which are generated, so the overlaying text itself cannot be part of the static background-image.

The main user interaction will be swiping within the center blob, displaying summaries of the items that are conceptually contained within the blobs underlying data store. Now and then, the user will drag and drop the item to one of the other blobs. While dragging, the item should be traced by a line and when dropping on the other blob, the item should be animated to look like it's being "sucked into" the blob.

Now, what kind of technique would you suggest for this app? Is Cocoa suitable in this scenario? Should I use a game framework like Cocos2D? All kinds of suggestions including example code snippets are most welcome.

I realize that this question might not be as straightforward and to the point as questions generally are on SO, but I hope your answers will come to use by more people than me. Thanks!

**EDIT (MY SOLUTION):**
I eventually ended up doing everything in UIKit, which was a lot easier than I expected.
Briefly described I used UIButtons with Custom style and an image background, which gave me full control over the visual appearance of the "items". I also found it very useful to manipulate the underlying CALayer of many of my other UIViews. It is often easier than drawing things from scratch using Core Graphics programming.

Another thing that was useful were the UIGestureRecognizer:s. I found them useful for both handling "real" gestures like swiping, longpress etc, but also for handling normal "tap" for UIView classes that aren't subclasses of UIControl. Two examples are UIImage, UILabel and UIView itself. That way I could handle taps for these simple classes. I could for example use a normal UIView, modify it's CALayer to change the look of it completely and still handle taps. Using this technique, I didn't have to subclass any views at all in my app.

The animations were pretty easy too, even though I had to use a non-public method to use "suck" animation, so my app will never pass App Store moderation. It was just a prototype anyway so I don't care.

When this app will be for real, I will probably implement it in HTML5/JavaScript wrapped by Phonegap. The reason for this is mainly reuse of existing mobile web services and also for code reuse across platforms. It will probably also be easier to hook into the existing security solution when using a webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2d is great if you need to move elements around really fast as it is a layer on top of OpenGLES. I think from what you have said the UIKit will be fine, you get nice animation support, you can do some nice things with UIScrollViews to handle moving elements around etc.

If you need more detailed graphics support and lots of moving elements, particle effects etc then by all means go for Cocos2D but be aware that in Cocos2d the application works more on a scheduled update method, i.e. you get notified every 1/60th of a second to move stuff draw stuff etc, whereas with normal UIKit approach it is more event drive, i.e. I click a button and show a view etc.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll have a go with Cocos2D. Personally, I find UIKit confusing and limiting. I constantly run into dead ends where things simply cannot be done or situations where I can't figure out why things go wrong. It often turns out that I forgot to override some obscure method or click some setting in Interface Builder, which changes the behavior of the app in a fundamental way. But, it is probably due to my huge UIKit knowledge gaps. Everything I don't understand is of course confusing ;)

Comment: I eventually ended up doing everything in UIKit, which was a lot easier than I expected. Maybe UIKit isn't as confusing and limiting as i thought before (Before i really tried to learn it :)

Comment: Good stuff, btw, I have a nice UIView+Layout category, to help with positioning, layering etc which you may find useful, grab the code from here.... http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/how-categories-can-simplify-your-code/